# XmlReader can't parse XML with <qn:xxxxx> format?

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I am trying to parse the following xml string:

```
<qn:QueryNotification xmlns:qn="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/QueryNotification" id="307" type="change" source="data" info="insert" database_id="6" sid="0x010500000000000515000000AEA63BDE2DE94B9FF38541A8CD1A0000">
  <qn:Message>Custom</qn:Message>
</qn:QueryNotification>
```

I am using an XmlReader in the following way:

```
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(z)))
{
     xmlReader.Read();
}
```

When Read() is executed, I get the following exception:

> XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 40.

I don't think it likes the qn: before each tag. How can I setup the XmlReader to parse this document?

Comment: What exactly is the value of `z`? It says the error is at 'position 40', but 40 characters into the xml that you posted in the question is in the middle of the namespace URI. And if I use your code with `var z="<qn:QueryNotification xmlns:qn=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/...`, I get no error. This tells me that what you posted is _not_ the actual value of `z`.

Comment: Hmmm... I am parsing z from a Unicode string like this: string z = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(binaryString); I wonder if there are hidden invalid characters...

Comment: And what's binaryString? Can you just print the value of z?

Comment: The raw copy/paste value of z is <qn:QueryNotification xmlns:qn="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/QueryNotification" id="464" type="change" source="data" info="insert" database_id="6" sid="0x010500000000000515000000AEA63BDE2DE94B9FF38541A8CD1A0000"><qn:Message>Custom</qn:Message></qn:QueryNotification>

Comment: Pasting it into notepad shows the text smaller than it should be in certain locations. I am going to try to convert it to a UTF-8 string before parsing it.

Comment: @Random832 you were correct to be suspicious of the string z - the encoding is what was causing the issue. Striping the unicode characters caused the xmlreader to parse the xml without needing to add the namespace like you said.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml has namespace daclared. You should consider it when parsing nodes. I suggest you to use Linq to XML:

```
XNamespace qn = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/QueryNotification";
XElement notification = XElement.Parse(z);
var message = (string)notification.Element(qn + "Message"); // Custom
```